# Cookie syntax for django 1.0

Tags: django, cookies

I m using the fllowing code to set cookie in django 1.1 But the cookie get deleted every time the page refresh or during post in Ie 7 , Ie 8 and safari.For Firefox and chrome It works fine.

```
expiry_date=datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
resp.set_cookie('appl_keyVal', 40, max_age=24*60*60, expires=expiry_date)
```

Is the cookie syntax correct for django 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expires should be a string in the format "Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie

Comment: can you please tell in my code what expires value will get stored.Because when i check in browsers the cookie set to 1 day expire in firefox and chrome... but the cookie become session cookie in Ie and safari...